# How do I set a timer for my code to execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to see how big my compute this value.
How do I set the timer for 60 seconds to see how big my binom_coeff_recur to occur? I want to see how big the value of binom_coeff_recur produced by my computer.

```
import time

start = time.time()

def binom_coeff_recur(n, k):  #formula = n!/ k!(n-k)!
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1
    return binom_coeff_recur(n-1, k-1) + binom_coeff_recur(n-1, k)
```

Comment: You'd pass a time argument to the function as well (e.g. a timestamp of when it should stop processing), and then add another check like `if time() >= deadline: return k`…

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
import time

start = time.time()
stop = start + 60

def binom_coeff_recur(n, k):  #formula = n!/ k!(n-k)!
    if if time.time() >= stop:
      return k

    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1
    return binom_coeff_recur(n-1, k-1) + binom_coeff_recur(n-1, k)
```